# R moving average function to deal with values less window size

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205144/2296728) answer, I have used a moving average function for a window size of 2, 3 and 4.

```
require(zoo)
#MOVING AVERAGE FUNCTION
get.mav <- function(df, n = 2){
  if(length(df) < n){
    return(df)
  } 
  c(df[1:(n-1)],rollapply(df,width = n, mean, align="right"))
}

#DATA FRAME (dummy)
ID <- c("d","b","a","a","c","e","b","d","b","b")
Value <- c(4,5,5,3,2,1,6,9,5,5)
df <-data.frame(ID,Value)

# FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATION
df <- with(df,df[order(ID),])
df$mav2 <- unlist(aggregate(Value~ID,df,get.mav,na.action = NULL,n=2)$Value) 
df$mav3 <- unlist(aggregate(Value~ID,df,get.mav,na.action = NULL,n=3)$Value) 
df$mav4 <- unlist(aggregate(Value~ID,df,get.mav,na.action = NULL,n=4)$Value) 

#OUTPUT
ID  Value   mav2    mav3    mav4
a   5   5   5   5
a   3   4   3   3
b   5   5   5   5
b   6   5.5 6   6
b   5   5.5 5.3 5
b   5   5   5.3 5.25
c   2   2   2   2
d   4   4   4   4
d   9   6.5 9   9
e   1   1   1   1
```

The function `get.mav` works exactly the way it should. I want to change this function such that

For window size 3, if df length is 2, it takes the mean of those two elements rather than simply returning df.

Similarly for window size 4, if length is 3 or 2, it takes mean of those three or two elements rather simply returning df.

I tried the if statements but comparisons are not working correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each width use `ave` to to invoke `rollapplyr` by `ID`.  `partial = TRUE` in `rollapplyr` causes it to average partial number of points near the beginning.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x, group, w) {
   ave(x, group, FUN = function(x) rollapplyr(x, w, mean, partial = TRUE))
}

transform(df[order(df$ID), ], 
   mav2 = roll(Value, ID, 2), 
   mav3 = roll(Value, ID, 3), 
   mav4 = roll(Value, ID, 4)
)
```

or alternatively:

```
w <- 2:4
names(w) <- paste0("mav", w)

with(df[order(df$ID), ],
   data.frame(ID, Value, lapply(w, roll, x = Value, group = ID), check.names = FALSE)
)
```

Either gives:

```
   ID Value mav2     mav3     mav4
1   a     5  5.0 5.000000 5.000000
2   a     3  4.0 4.000000 4.000000
3   b     5  5.0 5.000000 5.000000
4   b     6  5.5 5.500000 5.500000
5   b     5  5.5 5.333333 5.333333
6   b     5  5.0 5.333333 5.250000
7   c     2  2.0 2.000000 2.000000
8   d     4  4.0 4.000000 4.000000
9   d     9  6.5 6.500000 6.500000
10  e     1  1.0 1.000000 1.000000
```

**Update:** Fixed.