# Moving avg 3 months Vs previous n months and not inclusive of the first 3?

Tags: r

Some data

```
df <- data.frame(
  dates = seq(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-12-01'), by = "month"),
  user_id = c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
  somenum = 1:12
)

 df
        dates user_id somenum
1  2018-01-01       a       1
2  2018-02-01       b       2
3  2018-03-01       c       3
4  2018-04-01       a       4
5  2018-05-01       b       5
6  2018-06-01       c       6
7  2018-07-01       a       7
8  2018-08-01       b       8
9  2018-09-01       c       9
10 2018-10-01       a      10
11 2018-11-01       b      11
12 2018-12-01       c      12
```

Using the answers e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198551/rolling-mean-moving-average-by-group-id-with-dplyr), I am able to calculate a 3 months rolling average. The solutions arrange the data in order of user, then use `rollapply()`.

This is fine for calculating the e.g. rolling 3 month `average` for a `user_id`. What if I wanted to calculate the rolling `average` from the previous 3 months to that, exclusive of the initial 3 months `mean`?

E.g. `user_id` '`c`' has a 3 months `average` of `12 + 9 + 6 = 27/3 = 9`. If wanted the previous 3 it would be just `mean(3) = 3`. If my data were longer there might have been 3 months going further back than the first inital 3.

The end goal is to analyse user behavior change... what is the ratio of somenum for a user in the most recent 3 months vs. the preceeding 3 months.

How could this be calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the rollmean argument align="left" to create a column and align="right" in another. if you want the function to be used even for groups with less than 3 observation, you have to usse the rollapply function with the argument partial=T.

Comment: Hi Andre. Thanks for answering but I'm not following. Are you able to expand upon your solution?

Comment: The align argument choses the reference point for the new value. if align is "left" the mean will be calculated starting with the value, if "right", ending with it. (take a look at ?rollaplly). The argument partial=T makes the mean to be calculated even if there are missing values close to it. (you might also use functions such as lag and lead)