# Calculate Average of the last 3M values of data frame and add them to the data frame, repeating this 18 times, without using a loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am trying to calculate the mean of the last 3M value and add them to the bottom of the data frame and then use those value to calculate the mean for 3M (which is basically 2 months of data plus the newly added mean) and repeat this 18 times.

I am trying to find an efficient way of doing this, which less time consuming. I tired to do it with a double loop but then found a way use one loop and `lapply()`.

But I would like to know if there is a better way to do this by avoiding the loop.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(clock)
library(lubridate)
library(tsibble)

df <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X- X/X/Book7.xlsx",sheet = "Loop")

freq = 18

colnames(df)[1]="Dates"
Dates <- df$Dates

Working <- df[,-1] 

#--------------------------------------- Creation of Functions ---------------------------------------#

Moving_Average_3M <- function(Working)
{
  last_3_row <- tail(Working,3)
  
  # Convert the `last_3_row` object to a two-dimensional object as tail() function returns a vector
  last_3_row_df <- data.frame(last_3_row)
  
  # Calculate the mean of the last three rows
  mean_last_3 <- data.frame(colMeans(last_3_row_df,na.rm = TRUE))
  
  return(mean_last_3)
}

Rename_Col_and_bind <- function(Working,Output)
{
  colnames(Output) <- colnames(Working)
  
  Working <- rbind(Working,Output)
  
  return(Working)
}

#--------------------------------------- End of Creation of Functions ---------------------------------------#

#------------------------------------------ Loops for Execution ---------------------------------------------#

for(i in 1:freq)
{
  Output <- data.frame(lapply(Working,Moving_Average_3M))
  
  Working <- Rename_Col_and_bind(Working,Output)
  
}

view(Output)
```

The data frame, I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(Dates = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01"), `XYZ|851` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 
957, 829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 
1015, 827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 239, 5400, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 
33, 27, 28, 46, 11, 55, 47), `XYZ|574` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 74, 179, 464, 880, 324, 184, 90, 170, 140, 96, 78, 83, 
83, 121, 245, 9000, 332, 123, 117, 138, 20, 42, 70, 70, 42, 103, 
490, 7500, 488, 245, 142, 95, 63, 343, 57, 113, 100, 105)), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As mentioned, the minimalistic output after two iteration is given below:
This was the loop used here to get the two iterations:

```
for(i in 1:2)
{
  Output <- data.frame(lapply(Working,Moving_Average_3M))
  
  Working <- Rename_Col_and_bind(Working,Output)
  
}
```

The dput for `Working` data frame is given below:

```
 structure(list(`XYZ|851` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 
1814, 2324, 772, 1116, 1636, 1906, 957, 829, 911, 786, 938, 1313, 
2384, 1554, 1777, 1635, 1534, 1015, 827, 982, 685, 767, 511, 
239, 5400, 1301, 426, 261, 201, 33, 27, 28, 46, 11, 55, 47, 37.6666666666667, 
46.5555555555556), `XYZ|574` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 74, 
179, 464, 880, 324, 184, 90, 170, 140, 96, 78, 83, 83, 121, 245, 
9000, 332, 123, 117, 138, 20, 42, 70, 70, 42, 103, 490, 7500, 
488, 245, 142, 95, 63, 343, 57, 113, 100, 105, 106, 103.666666666667
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
"43", "44", "45", "46", "last_3_row", "last_3_row1"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To explain this further, I am adding an excel image for clarity:

The image in blue is the output which is same as the output you see in the `Working` data frame and the formulae which is used is highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling mean (moving average) by group/id with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198551/rolling-mean-moving-average-by-group-id-with-dplyr)

Comment: @SamR No Rolling Mean which is moving average and the average of 3M is different. The math used is different. So it wont. Thank you for the help tho.

Comment: It may help if you include the results of at least two iterations of your cycle to this sample data. You might find it simpler to reduce your data to be only a few columns (since it seems what works on two will work the same on the other eight) and perhaps a dozen or so rows (since it seems your data varies seasonally).

Comment: OK I'll withdraw my duplicate vote but as @r2evans says, can you give a _minimal_ example (with some expected output)? I'll take your word that what you're asking is different, but it's not clear to me what exactly it is.

Comment: Is the idea here to make a naive forecast from the average of the prior 3 rows, and then use that new value to make a new forecast, and so on? Algebraically, this will converge toward values that are a weighted average of the last three values, i.e. 1/2 the last value + 1/3 of the penultimate value and 1/6 of the antepenultimate value.

Comment: @r2evans Hi, I have added the output which we get after two iterations of the loop. Also reduced the data frame for ease. Hopefully this is what you were asking for. And I would appreciate if you could let me know how to approach this.

Comment: @SamR I have added the minial example and the expected output after 2 iterations. Can you have a look and let me know.

Comment: @JonSpring I have added an image which shows the value and the expected calculation. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts before the resolution:

- this is a cumulative mean, so a simple vectorized calc won't work
- this isn't a *rolling* operation
- this is a *reduction* (ala `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce`), since the calculation of one value relies on the rows (and calculations) before it; it's more of a recursive approach, though we won't explicitly use recursion for this
- side note: iteratively adding (`rbind`) rows to an object works in concept but is horribly inefficient and scales poorly; as such, instead of `rbind`ing in each iteration, I'll preallocate the space once (filled with `NA`) and fill the rows with new values

```r
# preallocate the extra rows
Working2 <- rbind(Working, Working[1:18,][NA,])

for (i in (nrow(Working)+1):nrow(Working2)) 
  Working2[i,-1] <- lapply(Working2[i - 1:3,-1], mean)
as.data.frame(Working2)
#         Dates    XYZ|851   XYZ|574
# 1  2019-01-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 2  2019-02-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 3  2019-03-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 4  2019-04-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 5  2019-05-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 6  2019-06-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 7  2019-07-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 8  2019-08-01    0.00000    0.0000
# 9  2019-09-01    0.00000   74.0000
# 10 2019-10-01  206.00000  179.0000
# 11 2019-11-01 1814.00000  464.0000
# 12 2019-12-01 2324.00000  880.0000
# 13 2020-01-01  772.00000  324.0000
# 14 2020-02-01 1116.00000  184.0000
# 15 2020-03-01 1636.00000   90.0000
# 16 2020-04-01 1906.00000  170.0000
# 17 2020-05-01  957.00000  140.0000
# 18 2020-06-01  829.00000   96.0000
# 19 2020-07-01  911.00000   78.0000
# 20 2020-08-01  786.00000   83.0000
# 21 2020-09-01  938.00000   83.0000
# 22 2020-10-01 1313.00000  121.0000
# 23 2020-11-01 2384.00000  245.0000
# 24 2020-12-01 1554.00000 9000.0000
# 25 2021-01-01 1777.00000  332.0000
# 26 2021-02-01 1635.00000  123.0000
# 27 2021-03-01 1534.00000  117.0000
# 28 2021-04-01 1015.00000  138.0000
# 29 2021-05-01  827.00000   20.0000
# 30 2021-06-01  982.00000   42.0000
# 31 2021-07-01  685.00000   70.0000
# 32 2021-08-01  767.00000   70.0000
# 33 2021-09-01  511.00000   42.0000
# 34 2021-10-01  239.00000  103.0000
# 35 2021-11-01 5400.00000  490.0000
# 36 2021-12-01 1301.00000 7500.0000
# 37 2022-01-01  426.00000  488.0000
# 38 2022-02-01  261.00000  245.0000
# 39 2022-03-01  201.00000  142.0000
# 40 2022-04-01   33.00000   95.0000
# 41 2022-05-01   27.00000   63.0000
# 42 2022-06-01   28.00000  343.0000
# 43 2022-07-01   46.00000   57.0000
# 44 2022-08-01   11.00000  113.0000
# 45 2022-09-01   55.00000  100.0000
# 46 2022-10-01   47.00000  105.0000
# 47       <NA>   37.66667  106.0000
# 48       <NA>   46.55556  103.6667
# 49       <NA>   43.74074  104.8889
# 50       <NA>   42.65432  104.8519
# 51       <NA>   44.31687  104.4691
# 52       <NA>   43.57064  104.7366
# 53       <NA>   43.51395  104.6859
# 54       <NA>   43.80049  104.6305
# 55       <NA>   43.62836  104.6843
# 56       <NA>   43.64760  104.6669
# 57       <NA>   43.69215  104.6606
# 58       <NA>   43.65604  104.6706
# 59       <NA>   43.66526  104.6660
# 60       <NA>   43.67115  104.6658
# 61       <NA>   43.66415  104.6675
# 62       <NA>   43.66685  104.6664
# 63       <NA>   43.66738  104.6666
# 64       <NA>   43.66613  104.6668
```

You can then fill in the `Dates` as desired.

(I used `as.data.frame(Working2)` solely to show all of it with all decimals, since `tibble`'s print method often hides some precision.)

Comment: Thank you for this. This works, but in the end we still have to use the loop for implementation of mean, and instead of `colMeans()`, you used direct `mean()` function to calculate the average of the value. 
Instead of using `tail()` function, you set `Working2[i - 1:3,-1]` to select the last 3 values excluding the date column.

Comment: One question I don't understand why `rbind()` ing the output data frame and appending it to add it to the existing data frame is inefficient. Could you please explain that part of it. The idea behind it was I have a fixed data frame, the output would have the same amount of columns without any rearrangement thus giving it the same name. 
When its fixed and has no scope of change, how would it be inefficient. I would very much appreciate which scenario have I not considered, that could explain the inefficiency. (No offense as I am just trying to ask questions to learning, sorry it sounds rude)

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`. (This latter method does not work as well with this question, though.)

Comment: Understood. Still trying to figure out how this part works `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out)`

Comment: It calls `rbind` _once_, vice calling it 18 times when row-by-row. With the _single_ call, it copies all of both frames _once_. With the 18 calls, it copies the original and the one row, and then combines them; then it copies the new original and the next one row, and then combines them; repeat 16 more times.

Comment: But again ... the `out <- list()` approach does not work as well here, the pre-allocation appears to work sufficiently well without repeated `rbind`ing.