Aggregate filtered data from column in dataset in R
I have a dataset in R similar to this
df
day   team   data
1     A      5
1     B      2
1     C      1
2     A      2
2     B      3
2     C      1
3     A      0
3     B      2
3     C      1
...   ...    ...

I now want to calculate the mean of data conditionally based on day and team which shall be added to every line in the dataset. The mean shall be calculated based on team and all previous lines where day is within a certain range compared to the day in the line. The range shall be defined by a variable.
For example if range <- 2 the mean shall be calculated for every team as followed:
day   team   data   mean
1     A      5      5
1     B      2      2
1     C      1      1
2     A      2      3.5
2     B      3      2.5
2     C      1      1
3     A      0      1
3     B      2      2.5
3     C      1      1
...   ...    ...    ...

How can I achieve this for example with aggregate()?

Sounds like you want a rolling mean. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198551/rolling-mean-moving-average-by-group-id-with-dplyr. Do you have gaps in the your days that you need to account for?

This is typically called a "rolling mean" or a "moving average". Here's a few questions with answers for doing this, Rolling mean/moving average with dplyr, Rolling mean (moving avg) by group, rolling means by group.

@GregorThomas Damn, you are right. As simple as that. I'm looking for moving average by group. That makes it much easier to search. Thanks.

Based on the comments above the solution was simpler then expected by calculating the moving average with the package zoo as followed
First order and group data by team and day
df <- df[order(df$team, df$day), ]
df <- group_by(df, team)

Then appending the moving average
df <- mutate(df, moving_avg2 =rollmean(team, k=2, fill=NA, align='right'))


This can be compactly written as: library(dplyr); library(zoo); df %>% arrange(team, day) %>% mutate(ma = rollmeanr(data, 2, fill = NA), .by = team) .  Note the r at the end of rollmeanr to get right alignment.

If you need to use aggregate, ensure first the data is sorted by day as given above, then do:
n <- 2
aggregate(df, data~team, \(x)rowMeans(embed(c(rep(NA, n-1), x), n), na.rm = TRUE))

  team data.1 data.2 data.3
1    A    5.0    3.5    1.0
2    B    2.0    2.5    2.5
3    C    1.0    1.0    1.0


If you want it in the format given above, using base R:
df|>
   aggregate(data~team, \(x)rowMeans(embed(c(rep(NA, n-1), x), n), na.rm = TRUE))|>
   do.call(what = data.frame)|>
   reshape(-1,dir='long', idvar = 'team', timevar = 'day', new.row.names = rownames(df))

  team day data
1    A   1  5.0
2    B   1  2.0
3    C   1  1.0
4    A   2  3.5
5    B   2  2.5
6    C   2  1.0
7    A   3  1.0
8    B   3  2.5
9    C   3  1.0

